# Create Generalised Anchor tag in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

In HTML we often write content within a `<p>` tag, and when we want some part of the text to act as a link we enclose that part with `<a>` tags, with a `href` attribute.

```
<p>Click <a href='./path/to/page'>me</a></p>
```

I am trying to do something similar in React, but cannot really figure out how to do it in a sensible way.

I have a `<P>` component which has a click handler. This click-handler is fired with a unique reference, which then updates the state of `<P>`. The `<P>` component has some text as children, and within that text I want to enclose some text with `<A>` tags which will take a unique reference as a prop, and when that text is clicked it fires the click handler in `<P>`.

```
<P>Click <A uniqueRef='foo'>me</A></P>

const A = ({children, uniqueRef}) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    //fireClickHandlerInP(uniqueRef)
  }
  return <a onClick={handleClick}>{children}</a>
}
```

So essentially I am trying to make a generalised anchor tag, which rather than opening a new page upon click updates the state of a component in React.

But how do I do this? How can I make the `<A>` tag fire the click handler in `<P>` in a sensible way?

I did manage to pull it off by simply passing `<A>` the click handler as a prop, along with its reference. However in this context it seems like a silly option. I have a very large file which will require a lot of these `<A>` tags, and passing the click handler as a prop every single time seems a bit contrived, just as it would if we needed to pass some click handler to all our `<a>` tags in HTML. So although it works, it seems to be a bit of a 'code smell' and will make the file look very messy. All the `<A>` tags are also used in another file so having it littered with another component's props seems illogical.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<P>Click <A uniqueRef='foo'>me</A></P>

const A = ({children, uniqueRef}) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    //fireClickHandlerInP(uniqueRef)
  }
  return <a onClick={()=> this.handleClick()}>{children}</a>
}
```